# How do I print the output onto a txt file: Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, output

This is my first time asking a question.  I am just starting to get into programming, so i am beginning with Python.  So I've basically got a random number generator inside of a while loop, thats inside of my "r()' function.  What I want to do is take all of the numbers (basically like an infinite amount  until i shut down idle) and put them into a text file.  Now i have looked for this on the world wide web and have found solutions for this, but on a windows computer.  I have a mac with python 2.7.  ANY HELP IS VERY MUCH APPRECIATED!  My current code is below

```
from random import randrange
def r():
    while True:
        print randrange(1,10)
```

Comment: The Windows solutions will work exactly the same for you, just with a different path.

Comment: Just pipe it to the file using redirection... `python [script.py] > foo`

Comment: See [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to `open` the file, `write` to it (as many times as you need to), and `close` it. This is explained in the tutorial under [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

The `with` statement (described toward the end of that section) is a great way to make sure the file always gets `close`d. (Otherwise, when you stopped your script with ^C, the file might end up missing the last few hundred bytes, and you'd have to use `try`/`finally` to handle that properly.)

The `write` method on files isn't quite as "friendly" as the `print` statement—it doesn't automatically convert things to strings, add a newline at the end, accept multiple comma-separated values, etc. So usually, you'll want to use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) to do that stuff for you.

For example:

```
def r():
    with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as f:
        while True:
            f.write('{}\n'.format(randrange(1, 10)))
```

Comment: Alright so i tried doing this and nothing happened....and its not me.  I copied this code and pasted it into the idle.  Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @user2701400: Well… did you actually add a call to `r()`? Are you sure the directory you're looking in is the same as the current working directory you're running from? Without a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) nobody can debug your code…

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call the function and then redirect the output to a file or use the python API to write to a file. Your whole script could be:

```
from random import randrange
def r():
    while True:
        print randrange(1,10)
r()
```

Then you can run `python script_name.py > output.txt`

If you'd like to use the python API to write to a file, your script should be modified to something like the following:

```
from random import randrange
def r():
    with open('somefile.txt', 'w') as f:
        while True:
            f.write('{}\n'.format(randrange(1,10)))
r()
```

The with statement will take care of closing the file instance appropriately.